# Fetching JSON with %20 in the link

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsurl

I have variable date=@"2014-06-18 12:59:46"
I do the following:

```
NSString* formated_date = [[Constants shared].date  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%%20"];
```

which gives me the wanted output of the new-formed variable: "2014-06-18%2012:59:46".

Now, when I put all that into string, which represents the url, I cannot fetch `JSON` from within the app.

BUT, when i `NSLog` the generated url, and copy paste it in browser - it works.
Also, if i take, c/p the Logged url, and hardcode it into the json request, I get the demanded json just as intended.

This is my code so far:

```
NSString* formated_date = [[Constants shared].date  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%%20"];
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                 @"http://api.fessor.da.kristoffer.office/homework?rest&_rp[date]=%@&_rp[uuid]=%@&_rp[workspace]=parents&_rp[token]=%@&_rp[user_id]=%@&child_id=%@&type=parents&start_date=%@&end_date=%@",
                 formated_date,[Constants shared].uuid,[Constants shared].token,[Constants shared].user_id, [Constants shared].user_id,[Constants shared].start_date, [Constants shared].end_date
                 ];
NSLog(url);

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    //Load the json on another thread
    [Constants shared].jsonDataHomework = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                                   [NSURL URLWithString:url"]];


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self getPresentHomework];            

    });

});
```

`[self getPresentHomework]` then returns an error, since the data from the json is `nil`.

I repeat once again, i get nil data when the code for fetching json is like this:

```
[Constants shared].jsonDataHomework = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                                   [NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

but if i hardcode the url, then i get the desired result

```
[Constants shared].jsonDataHomework = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                                   [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.fessor.da.kristoffer.office/homework?rest&_rp[date]=2014-06-18%2012:59:46&_rp[uuid]=289A6F6F-BB71-444A-B16B-DCAF0070E1D3&_rp[workspace]=parents&_rp[token]=7fe3768108445570f11bf333cb821b0bee9213d2cced91a1f63f8c648fbc3e6a&_rp[user_id]=22066&child_id=22066&type=parents&start_date=2014-06-18&end_date=2014-06-18"]];
```

What am I doing wrong?
Should I change the order of threads or something like that?

Comment: How can you be sure that it's the date which causes error?

Comment: Because if I hardcode the date, everything works

Comment: Try append your parameters to the URL string without adding percentage and then use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` before assign it to your `NSURL`

Comment: This is actually the correct answer.
Write the new one, so I can accept it.
The point is, for reasons unknown, to first append parameters, and then call stringByAddingPercentage and then use it as an url

Comment: Already, glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to append your parameters to the URL string without adding percentage and then use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` before assigning it to your `NSURL`.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                 @"format your url"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL string contain special character so use

```
NSString *strUrl=[@"http://api.fessor.da.kristoffer.office/homework?rest&_rp[date]=2014-06-18%2012:59:46&_rp[uuid]=289A6F6F-BB71-444A-B16B-DCAF0070E1D3&_rp[workspace]=parents&_rp[token]=7fe3768108445570f11bf333cb821b0bee9213d2cced91a1f63f8c648fbc3e6a&_rp[user_id]=22066&child_id=22066&type=parents&start_date=2014-06-18&end_date=2014-06-18" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: You mean instead of "[Constants shared].jsonDataHomework = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                                   [NSURL URLWithString:url]];" i should write "[Constants shared].jsonDataHomework = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                                   [NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];"

Comment: Well, as i've said..I do make and NSLog the proper string url.
And I have tried this that you proposed, and it's not working.
Could you be more specific?